# Efficiently formatting discord.py

Tags: discord.py

my discord bot is nearly done. It just takes 6 users and throws them into an array and then shuffles up the 6 players into 2 teams of 3. However, this code looks disgusting imo. Is there any way to format this more efficiently? For example, possibly make an embedded class and then call the class when I need to embed something?

This is what the final embed looks like: [Embedded Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMD7E.png)

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import utils
import discord
import asyncio
import random
import math



class queue(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.qcount = 0
        self.total = []
        

    @commands.command()
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        if self.qcount < 6:
           self.total
           self.qcount += 1
           await ctx.send('Added to the queue!' + ' ' + f'{ctx.author.mention}')
           self.total.append(ctx.author.mention)
           if self.qcount == 6:
             await ctx.send('Queue ready, the teams are:')
             random.shuffle(self.total)
             blue = self.total[:3]
             orange = self.total [3:]
             guild = ctx.guild
             overwrites = {
              guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
              guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
             }
             teamNumber = (random.randint(1,999))
             blueVoice = await guild.create_voice_channel('Blue Team' + ' ' + str(teamNumber), user_limit = 3, overwrites=overwrites)
             orangeVoice = await guild.create_voice_channel('Orange Team' + ' ' + str(teamNumber), user_limit = 3, overwrites=overwrites)
             embed1 = discord.Embed(
               title = 'Blue Team',
               description = 'Your voice channel is: ' + str(blueVoice) + '\n' + f'{blue}',
               colour = discord.Colour.blue()
             )
             await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
             embed2 = discord.Embed(
               title = 'Orange Team',
               description = 'Your voice channel is: ' + str(orangeVoice) + '\n' + f'{orange}',
               colour = discord.Colour.orange()
             )
             await ctx.send(embed=embed2)
        else:
            await ctx.send('Queue full, please wait for the current queue to close.')
        return


def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(queue(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing something like this using `.join()` to organize the list would be better.

```py
embed1 = discord.Embed(
    title = 'Blue Team',
    description = f'Your voice channel is: {str(blueVoice)}\n {"\n".join(orange)}',
    colour = discord.Colour.blue())

await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
```

Note: This is how you should use f string, if you used `+` no need to type `f` before it

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that and also just separate each different group of related functioning code with comments.